# How to save image in class object?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

Can anyone help me to solve my prob?

Declare variable as

```
               public class SaveMypet
               {
                     public ImageSource  PetImage { get; set; }
               }
```

On button click my code is

```
                  SaveMypet savepet = new SaveMypet();
                  savepet.PetImage = pet_image.Source;
```

Is it right way to store image to a class object...??

Answer (score 0):

If by *save image to a class* you mean assigning it to a container, then sure. Be aware, though, that this does not save the image itself anywhere else in the device storage. So the moment this class, or the original source, is destroyed, so will be your image.

Besides, `ImageSource` does not carry the image binary data, but rather a reference to it.

Comment: Problem solved...thank you...I have used Bitmapsource instead Imagesource.